# Passing input type file through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, api

So I am trying to pass a file through Ajax along with other data in the form. Every data except the file is getting passed. I am sending an email with all the data using php. I am new to Ajax and tried many ways. But still not sure where I am going wrong.

So here is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submitbtn").click(function(){
var uname = $("#uname").val();
var uemail= $("#uemail").val();
var subject= $("#subject").val();
var resume= $('input[type=file]').val();
var message= $("#message").val();

  if(uname == '')
   {
     $("#errormsgs1").html("Please Enter Name");
     $("#uname").css("border","1px solid #f00");
     $("#uname").focus();
      return false;
   }
  if(uemail == '')
   {
     $("#errormsgs2").html("Please Enter Email");
     $("#uemail").css("border","1px solid #f00");
     $("#uemail").focus();
      return false;
   }

  if(subject == '')
   {
     $("#errormsgs3").html("Please Enter Subject");
     $("#subject").css("border","1px solid #f00");
     $("#subject").focus();
      return false;
   }

  if(resume == '')
   {
     $("#errormsgs4").html("Please Enter Your Resume");
     $("#resume").css("border","1px solid #f00");
     $("#resume").focus();
      return false;
   }
  if(message == '')
   {
     $("#errormsgs5").html("Please Enter Message");
     $("#message").css("border","1px solid #f00");
     $("#message").focus();
      return false;
   }


$("form#data").submit(function(){

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: mycareer.php,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
});
```

Below is the mycareer.php file

```
<?php
$uname       = $_POST['uname'];
print_r($uname);
$uemail      = $_POST['uemail'];
print_r($uemail);
//$subject     = $_POST['subject'];
$resume       = $_FILES['resume'];
print_r($resume );
$message     = $_POST['message'];
print_r($message );


if($uname !='' && $uemail !='')
{

$to = 'sayantan.m@gmail.in';
$subject = "My Career";
$message ='<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
<title>Mycareer.in</title>
<style type="text/css">
div, p, a, li, td {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
}
.ReadMsgBody {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
.ExternalClass {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  line-height:100%;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
}
table[class=full] {
  padding:0 !important;
  border:none !important;
}
table td img[class=imgresponsive] {
  width:100% !important;
  height:auto !important;
  display:block !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
body {
 width:auto!important;
}
table[class=full] {
 width:100%!important;
}
table[class=devicewidth] {
 width:100% !important;
 padding-left:20px !important;
 padding-right: 20px!important;
}
table td img.responsiveimg {
 width:100% !important;
 height:auto !important;
 display:block !important;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
table[class=devicewidth] {
 width:100% !important;
}
table[class=inner] {
 width:100%!important;
 text-align: center!important;
 clear: both;
}
table td a[class=top-button] {
 width:160px !important;
  font-size:14px !important;
 line-height:37px !important;
}
table td[class=readmore-button] {
 text-align:center !important;
}
table td[class=readmore-button] a {
 float:none !important;
 display:inline-block !important;
}
.hide {
 display:none !important;
}
table td[class=smallfont] {
 border:none !important;
 font-size:26px !important;
}
table td[class=sidespace] {
 width:10px !important;
}
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

 table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td[class=template-img] img {
 width:100% !important;
 display:block !important;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background:#f2f2f2;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="full">
  <tr>
    <td height="54">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
        <tr>
          <td><table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="full" style="border-radius:5px 5px 0 0; background-color:#ffffff;">
              <tr>
                <td height="29">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="inner" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="23" class="hide">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td height="75" class="inner" valign="middle"><a href="#"><img class="logo" src="http://my.in/img/my-logo.png" width="180" height="61" alt="Logo" style="background: #000;padding: 10px;"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" class="inner" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                    <tr>
                      <td height="15">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center"><a href="http://my.in/" class="top-button" style="font:bold 13px/37px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; background:#f47920; display:block; border-radius:24px; text-transform:uppercase;">View online</a></td>
                      <td class="hide" width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb;">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
        <tr>
          <td><table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="full" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
              <tr>
                <td height="23">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="23" class="sidespace">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td><table width="76%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="inner" id="banner" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                          <!--<tr>
                            <td style="font:bold 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-right:1px solid #dbdbdb;color: #000;" class="smallfont">THE BEST NUTRITION PLANS ARE HERE</td>
                          </tr>-->
                          <tr>
                            <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--<table width="22%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" class="inner" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/quanutrition.bangalore?fref=ts" style="margin-top:5px; display:inline-block;"><img src="http://www.quanutrition.com/images/facebook.png" width="32" height="atuo" alt="Social Media" /></a></td>
                            <td align="center"><a href="https://twitter.com/Qua_Nutrition?lang=en" style="margin-top:5px; display:inline-block;"><img src="http://www.quanutrition.com/images/twitter.png" width="32" height="atuo" alt="Social Media" /></a></td>
                            <td align="center"><a href="https://plus.google.com/+quanutritionbestdietplans" style="margin-top:5px; display:inline-block;"><img src="http://www.quanutrition.com/images/google.png" width="32" height="atuo" alt="Social Media" /></a></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>--></td>
                      <td width="23" class="sidespace">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <!--<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="3.33%" class="sidespace">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td width="93.33%"><img class="imgresponsive" src="http://www.quanutrition.com/images/banner1.jpg" width="554" height="atuo" alt="Banner" /></td>
                      <td width="3.33%" class="sidespace">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>-->
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="23" class="sidespace">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="inner">
                          <tr>
                            <td style="font:15px/19px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom: 8px;width: 20%;color: #000;" class="smallfont">Name </td>
                            <td style="font:15px/19px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom: 8px;color: #000;" class="smallfont" width="23">'.$uname.'</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="font:15px/19px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom: 8px;color: #000;" class="smallfont">Email </td>
                            <td style="font:15px/19px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom: 8px;color: #000;" class="smallfont" width="23">'.$uemail.'</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="font:15px/19px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom: 8px;color: #000;" class="smallfont">Mobile </td>
                            <td style="font:15px/19px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom: 8px;color: #000;" class="smallfont" width="23">'.$resume.'</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td style="font:15px/19px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom: 8px;color: #000;" class="smallfont">Message:</td>
                            <td style="font:15px/19px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom: 8px;color: #000;" class="smallfont" width="23">'.$message.'</td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="hide" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
</td>
                      <td width="23" class="sidespace">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td height="16">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td height="16">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td height="16">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb;">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="full">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
        <tr>
          <td><table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="full" style="border-radius:0 0 7px 7px;">
              <tr>
                <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><table class="inner" align="right" width="340" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; text-align:center;">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="21">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                          <tr>
                            <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="full">

                                <tr>
                                  <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                              </table></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table class="inner" align="left" width="230" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; text-align:center;">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="21">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="font:11px Helvetica,  Arial, sans-serif; color:#000000;">&copy; 2017, All rights reserved </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                      <td width="21">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: mail@my.in' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-to: '.$uemail.'' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Cc: rajendra.b@my.in' . "\r\n";
$sent = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
  echo "Thankyou for Contacting with us. We will get back you soon !!.";
}
else
{
  echo "Please enter all the fields.";
}
?>
```

Below is the form

```
<form action="purpledotcareer.php" id="fileUploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkvalidate()">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Enter Your Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" onfocus="this.value = '';" required="" type="text" value="" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control"  id="uemail" name="uemail" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" onfocus="this.value = '';" required="" type="text" value=""  >
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Message:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" onfocus="this.value = '';" required="" rows="3" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Upload Resume:</label> 
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="resume" name="resume" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" onfocus="this.value = '';" required="" accept=".xlsx,.xls,.doc, .docx,.ppt, .pptx,.txt,.pdf" >
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
```

It will be really helpful if anybody can solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which variable referred by the "file"  ? Make sure :
0). enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute is appear inside your form tag opener
 
1). Your file input has attribute type "file" something like this : <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

2). Catch fileToUpload input with $_FILES

Comment: I have added that. It is already there.

Comment: @Brain90 see my recent edit. I have uploaded the form

Comment: Catch fileToUpload input with $_FILES - Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Try to change $resume  = $_POST['resume']; to $resume = $_FILES['resume'];

Comment: Yes I did that and it is working. But I am not exactly getting the way I want. See as you can see from my code I need to send the file through email. So when I am doing that. I am only getting the name. But I want to make it downloadable. How can I achieve that?

Comment: 1). Make a function to upload the $resume inside mycareer.php
2). Get the file upload location
3). Put location at 2nd step inside $message as hyperlink to download the file.


## As your code run successfully, refactor your code ASAP, jump to learn OOP with PHP. Use class, use mailer classes like swiftMailer, etc to make your job easier in the future. ##

Comment: How can I get the file upload location?

Comment: I am not understanding this part. It will be very kind of you if you can show it in the answer section.